# PHP: How to use function to either echo result or to save it in a variable (partially working)

Tags: php, function, variables, echo

I am new to PHP and hope someone can help me with this.

I have the following function to which I can pass an `itemID` (unique integer) which it will then use to return the corresponding translation from a previously created array (this is just the final part).

**PHP function (saved in my header file):**

```
function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID){
    foreach($trans as $key => $val){
        if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
            echo $val["trans"];
        }
    }
}
```

This works as intended as long as I refer to the function anywhere on an HTML page as follows.

**Echoing result on HTML page (working):**

```
echo fetchTransMain($trans, someID);
```

However, I have certain scenarios where instead of echoing the result to the page I need to save it as a variable. I tried the following but this still echoes it somewhere at the top of the screen.

**Save result to variable instead of echoing it (not working):**

```
$someVariable = fetchTransMain($trans, someID);
```

**Can someone tell me how I can use this function both to echo the result** (working part) **and to save it to a variable alternatively** (not working part) - as needed ?

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return the value in the function instead of echoing it:

```
function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID){
    foreach($trans as $key => $val){
        if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
            return $val["trans"];
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to print it you do:

```
echo fetchTransMain($trans, someID);
```

Otherwise you do:

```
$someVariable = fetchTransMain($trans, someID);
```

Comment: Oh man - this is so easy. ;) Thanks a lot - that's all I needed. Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tell me how I can use this function both to echo the result (working part) and to save it to a variable alternatively.

Some functions like [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) take an optional parameter to indicate if it should return the value, or just echo it, so this is a fair question. Here is the function signature for `print_r`:

> mixed print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )

If you'd like this functionality too, try passing in an optional 3rd parameter to indicate if you want your function to echo or return a value.

```
function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID, $echo = false){
    foreach($trans as $key => $val){
        if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
            if(!$echo) { 
               echo $val["trans"];   // Echo the value
            } else {
               return $val["trans"]; // Return the value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** It's much simpler to just return the value and echo it outside the function, but my answer is intended to be faithful to your exact question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as well. In my specific case it looks like the solution from Markus Funke is enough. However, I like this approach and will definitely use it for other things. :)

Comment: Oh the other approach is by far better. By far. I was trying to meet your exact requirements ;)

Comment: I know but this approach is still interesting and it definitely helped. Thanks again ! :)

Comment: There is a similar function called [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) which takes an optional parameter to echo or return a value. You might be interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID){
    foreach($trans as $key => $val){
        if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
            $tobePrint.= $val["trans"];
        }
    }
      return $tobePrint;
}
```

and use it with :

```
   print  fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID)
```

or

```
   $variable = fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible and extensible way to do this is to use the output buffer functions http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php.

```
function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID, $echo){
     $str="";
     ob_start();
     foreach($trans as $key => $val){
         if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
               echo $val["trans"];   // Echo the value
          }
     }

     $str = ob_get_buffer();
     if($echo) ob_end_flush();
     else ob_end();
     return $str;
}
```

*The code above isn't tested for functional or syntactical correctness, but it should work as-is or quite similar.*

Comment: The main trick is, that you don't need to change the original algorithm and the part within `ob_start` and `ob_end` can have nearly any complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value from function.
assuming you might have only one possible match try this.

```
function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID){
    foreach($trans as $key => $val){
        if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
            return $val["trans"];
        }
    }
}
```

and then call your function

```
$someVariable = fetchTransMain($trans, $someID);
```

and then echo returned value.

```
echo $someVariable;
```